# Search/Filtering functionality blocks the Main(GUI) thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, event-handling, wxwidgets

I have a custom table and I have implemented a search/filtering function which goes through all the elements in the table and then hides/shows the item in the table depending upon whether that item/element matches the one we are searching for.
For example, let's say I have a text control and I type "wxwidgets" in it then my custom function will go through all the elements in the table and hide the elements that do not match this "wxwidgets" entry. This works fine and I am correctly able to hide/show the elements. But the problem is that this search blocks the main thread(gui) since I am doing this in the main thread. The table has around 1000 entries or can be more in the future. My question is how can I avoid this blocking of the main thread. I am thinking of using another worker thread that will do this searching of elements. But then I read that "no secondary threads should call gui functions". But then how can i show/hide the elements of the table from the worker thread. For example, currently in the main thread I use Show(true) or Show(false) to show/hide a particular entry from the table and all this is done while I am in a for/while loop. But if i implement this(the for loop) in a worker thread then according to the quoted advice i should not use the Show() functions from inside that worker thread. What can be done in this situation? Also, is there any other way/advice of doing this searching for elements of the table. I am thinking of starting a new detachable thread every time the user enters some text in the text field. And then delete that old thread if the user appends some more text to the text field and start a new thread which starts searching from the beginning. Is this the right solution for this?

The problem is that inside my for loop i am using the wxWidgets functions. For example, this is what my for loop looks like:

```
void AnotherClass::onTextChanged(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    for(int i = 5; i<154;++i)
    {                                                                                                                        
        SomeClass *element = dynamic_cast<SomeClass*>(FindWindowById(i));
        if(element.GetLabel() == textEnteredInTextCtrl)                                          
        {                                                                                                                    
            element.Show(true);//element found                                                        
            //update the necessary layout here using layout call                                
        }                                                                                                                    
        else                                                                                                               
        {                                                                                                                     
            element.Show(false);//element not found                                                  
            //update the necessary layout here using Layout() call                             
        }                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                        
}
```

This is the main part of the search. Now inside the workerthread should/can i use the functions like FindWindowById() and GetLabel()? Are they considered GUI functions or not so that I can use them from the worker thread? Can i or can i not use FindWindowByID() and GetLabel() and other similar functions(like Layout() and Show()) from inside the worker thread. How should I make this work? I mean I know how to use wxThread and send events using QueueEvent and already have another worker thread in my program that does some other calculation but I am asking about how I should make it work in this particular case.

Another solution suggested by QuentinC would be to use a timer. His suggestion is as follows:

> In my case, I don't start refreshing the list immediately after the
> user has typed a letter in the search box. Instead, when the user has
> typed a letter (wxEVT_TEXT), I start or restart a timer of 500ms. Only
> when the timer goes out (the user stops typing for 500ms) then the list
> is refreshed. Again, this is a measure to avoid a rapid succession of
> useless refreshes.

But in this case of using a timer i have several queries. I am sending the wxEVT_TEXT from **CustomTextCtrl**'s onTextChanged method  to this class' onTextChanged method. I guess i could start the timer of 500ms inside the onTextChanged method of the CustomTextCtrl class when the user types a letter. But then where should i check that the timer is still running? In the CustomTextCtrl's onTextChanged method or inside the **AnotherClass**'s onTextChanged method?
So for **clarification** i have **two classes**:

1. the CustomTextCtrl class which have a onTextChanged method which uses event.Skip() to forward this event to its parent.
2. The parent class AnotherClass which also have a onTextChanged method and this method receives this forwarded event and do the searching and updates the table.

Where and how should i start/restart/stop the timer to update the UI?

NOTE: The process of filtering the elements is working perfectly but the only problem is that the main(GUI) thread is blocked when the user type some text inside the textctrl. After lets say 6 or 7 seconds, the text appears inside the textctrl and the UI is updated. I don't want this unresponsiveness of the main UI for 6-7 seconds.

Also, note that i am not using any wxList/wxGrid. I am just using wxPanels and wxStaticText and using show/hide on them.

**Edit:** One improvement in the code above is that to only use Layout() call from outside the for loop. If i use the Layout() calls from outside the for loop then the search functionality works almost instantly. But this(method) still has the potential of blocking the main thread in the future if the table has many more elements. So i want to use a thread or a timer method. But i don't know how the secondary thread could use the gui functions or how can/should i use a wxTimer method(if any) to solve this problem.

Comment: The first question I would ask myself is why filtering 1000 items is so slow?  On any reasonable modern CPU I would expect it to be much faster than 6-7 seconds (6-7 milliseconds would seem about right).  I suggest profiling the code during a filter operation to find out where the “hot spots” are—chances are it’s doing something grossly inefficient somewhere.

Comment: Btw using multiple threads probably isn’t a great idea; it’s going to complicate your code (and likely introduce race conditions) and doesn’t really solve the underlying problem anyway, which is that it takes too long for your view to update.  A multithreaded update would still take just as long (although the user could interact with the window during the update, but that’s not all that useful when the view is stale anyway)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Answer to your first question is: Lets say i type "wxwidgets" as fast as i can. So lets see what will happen. First the onTextChanged method for the letter "w" will be called and it will forward it to AnotherClass' method which will loop through all(1000) the table element. Meanwhile i have already typed the letter "x" after "w" so another wxEVT_TEXT  will fire up and again go through all the table element. This will happen for each letter of "wxwidgets" so obviously it will block the main thread since the old for loop is already going on.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner i have moved the layout() calls outside the for loop and now the search functionality works almost instantly. But  i am still looking for a thread or a timer method to solve this problem since in the future the table may have many more elements.

Comment: Unless you have an IO bound computation or a very complex/advanced computation to do, I do not expect the computation to be slow ton few character. Actually, not slower than user inputs. For big texts, I agree, although sometimes it is possible to perform an incremental computation (or at least partially incremental in most cases).

Comment: I assume using FindWindowById over a 100 times slows down the code.

Answer (score 2):

I have several thoughts on this subjet

A) If you have a speed issue, then you better profile your code, to see where the bottle neck is.

B) Calling GDI functions from a not-main thread is risky. Maybe just asking for window-id and its label is not that dangerous, but I think calling `Show()` definitely is.

C) This piece of code is mainly GUI related. I don't think a worker thread is useful here. But stacking similar callings may improve its speed. For this, I have three advises:

- 1. Use [CallAfter()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a63c7351618fd77330d80a250b3719519) passing the `elemnt.Show()` method
- 2. Use [Freeze()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a15c678314cfc1d807196bc298b713ed3) before the loop and [Thaw](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a279a532124073261b28131b6afb59a1e) after it.
- 3. Call `Layout()`only once, right after the loop. About this I wonder if `Show()/Hide()` controls is better than `Enable()/Disabñe()`

D) Because you call `FindWindowById()` so many times, and also many user changes, it will be better to cache all affected windows in a container (a `std::map` with `id` as the key). Then, inside the loop use the container instead of 'FindWindowById()`.

E) As a last resource, if the GUI is still blocked, use [wxYield()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#gac386c89a04e364afc07edce6d848c27a) every xxx (say 100) loop-iterations. Depending of pending messages this solution may get things worse (reentrances, crossed effects, etc).